# How do I get the stream revision for committed events read from an NEventStore IEventStream?

Tags: projection, neventstore

I'm working on a projections library intended to support parallelizing and distributing the processing of arbitrary streams of data. I'm using NEventStore as a reference use case. Unlike the NEventStore PollingClient, I'm not using a cursor over the entire event store, but rather a cursor per stream. But I've been unable to find a way, when reading a stream, to determine which events correspond to which stream revisions or checkpoints. Is there a straightforward way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

ICommit has a StreamRevision property:

```
_eventStore.Advanced.GetFrom().First().StreamRevision
```